# For the life of me, I can't figure out how to setup the Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm sorry, I know there are tons of tutorial on this and I tried and didn't work.

I have WAMP installed in c:. It's document root is d:/Sites/Wamp. I have been able to load regular html, php, wordpress and Code Igniter from there.

With Code Igniter, it was quite easy as I only had to copy paste the library into the d:/sites/Wamp folder and configure the database.

With the Zend framework, I'd like to do something similar where I'd just have to copy some files into the Wamp folder. Is that possible? I'd like to avoid using the Zend Tool for now. Could some point me in the right direction please with a tutorial or what files to copy over.

Comment: If you use Code Igniter, why Zend? T_T

Comment: I know environment setup is sometimes more difficult than actual problem. After going to same scene (but with Python, ROR, and and so on), I moved to Ubuntu and life become a bit easier.

Comment: yeah, I didn't noticed "regular html, php, wordpress and Code Igniter from there.". Wordpress from Zend ? Still my previous comment is valid.

Comment: Did you create a virtual host for it in Apache?

Comment: No, I didn't mean anything from Zend. I just mean I was able to make html, php, wordpress and CodeIgniter work with my WAMP stack on my development computer. I hadn't even tried Zend at that time. The reason I want to do Zend Framework is because I'm still learning web development and I'd like to be exposed to all of the major frameworks. Also, I'm not familiar with Virtual Hosts. Reading from Wikipedia, I think I understand what it is. I've been clearing my D:/Sites/Wamp folder whenever I start using a new framework.

Comment: Download the *Zend Framework 2.x.x Minimal* file from [here](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest#ZF2) and extract the files - all you really need is the folder "Zend" in "library" (it's usually a good idea to simply copy both "library" and "resources" over to your application directory). Unfortunately, the beginners tutorial is a quite bad one... to start on your own, you'll first of all need to add the path to the "Zend" folder to the include path (e.g., via `set_include_path` or in php.ini).

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you don't want to use Zend_Tool here is the default basic application structure:

```
project
|-- application
|   |-- Bootstrap.php
|   |-- configs
|   |   `-- application.ini
|   |-- controllers
|   |   |-- ErrorController.php
|   |   `-- IndexController.php
|   |-- models
|   `-- views
|       |-- helpers
|       `-- scripts
|           |-- error
|           |   `-- error.phtml
|           `-- index
|               `-- index.phtml
|-- library
|   `--Zend //zend framework  goes here ***
|-- public
|   |-- .htaccess
|   `-- index.php
`-- tests
    |-- application
    |   `-- bootstrap.php
    |-- library
    |   `-- bootstrap.php
    `-- phpunit.xml
```

In the Zend Framework download you will find the `library` folder and in there you will find the `Zend` folder. Copy the whole Zend folder to `project/library` so it will end up as `project/library/Zend/`

your default `.htaccess` will look like and belongs in the public folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

also in your public folder will be your `index.php` and will look like:

```
<?php
//the next line is optional and is only to remove the index.php from the url
//$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = str_replace('index.php', '', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

at `project/application/configs/` will live the `application.ini` file and in the beginning will look like:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

the default `Bootstrap.php` looks like:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
}
```

the default `indexController` looks like:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
    }
}
```

and finally the default error controller looks like:

```
class ErrorController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function errorAction()
    {
        $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');

        switch ($errors->type) {
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE:
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:

                // 404 error -- controller or action not found
                $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
                $this->view->message = 'Page not found';
                break;
            default:
                // application error
                $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(500);
                $this->view->message = 'Application error';
                break;
        }

        $this->view->exception = $errors->exception;
        $this->view->request   = $errors->request;
    }
}
```

now you should be able to accesyour project at the url `http://localhost/project/public` all request to a Zend Framework application will route through `index.php`.

I really recommend `Zend_Tool`, it was built for a reason.

If you need any more...RTM all of this is right out of the docs.

Comment: Alright, I will try it out once I'm home from work. I will eventually use the tool, but I just need to know I'm able to set it up without it and see how to do it manually at least once. Then I can really understand what the tool really does.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you setup a virtual host in apache here is what I have for a just a test environemnt on my WAMP installtion:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zend.local
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/zend/public"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/zend/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Obviously I also added a line to my host file to point zend.local to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think what this does is in case I have several sites on my development computer and they could conflict. This is very important info and I will be creating virtual hosts in the future. However, since I've been clearing my c:/wamp/www folder every time I start a new site, I don't think this helps me for now. I mean with code igniter, I just copy paste what I downloaded to the www folder and I get a welcome page instantly and can learn from there. With the Zend framework, is it possible to do something similar?

Comment: I'm by no means a Zend expert I have just downloaded it and played with it a few times. I personally am I big fan of Yii framework. But I went through a tutorial first time with Zend and I had to do setup stuff, it isn't just download and start playing with it.

Comment: Original, I'm considering giving it up for now and move on to Yii, CakePHP, Symphony, etc...

Comment: Either way (zend or yii or something else) your best bet is to find a decent tutorial and follow it the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest following Rob Allen's tutorial which you can find at http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/. This will suggest using Zend Tool to setup the skeleton app, but since you've said you don't want to do that you can download the finished code from his site and read through the tutorial to see how it was put together.